# pkstwo error in R

Tags: r, object, statistics

I am running the following code in R:

```
pkstwo <- function(x, tol = 1e-06) { 
  if (is.numeric(x)) 
    x <- as.double(x) 
  else stop("argument 'x' must be numeric") 
  p <- rep(0, length(x)) 
  p[is.na(x)] <- NA 
  IND <- which(!is.na(x) & (x > 0)) 
  if (length(IND)) 
    p[IND] <- .C(stats:::C_pkstwo, length(x[IND]), p = x[IND], 
                 as.double(tol), PACKAGE = "stats")$p 
  p 
}
```

But when I call `pkstwo(0.1)` I get the following error:

```
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'C_pkstwo' not found
```

Could anyone please help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The C code is now called C_pKS2, and is used in the private function pkstwo() within ks.test()

Run ks.test with no parentheses to see its R code.

```
ks.test
```

Run stats:::C_pKS2 for some more info.

```
stats:::C_pKS2
```